# How to Iterate over javascript Map using angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm developing an Angualr application where we have a `Map` object (as shown below). The key and value of the map object (`headerObj`) are coming from user as input to the app,

```
  var headerObj = new Map();
  headerObj.set(key,value);
```

I'm iterating through them using foreach as shown below, the output is coming as expected

```
           $scope.inputHeaders.forEach(function (headerkey, headervalue) {
                     console.log(headerkey, headervalue; 

                });
```

but I have to show this map values in UI, which again user can edit, so I have binded them

```
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="header in inputHeaders">
              <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in header">
                  {{key}} : {{value}}
             </div>
          </li>
```

I've googled and tried several ways, but nothing did help, so basically I've wanted to know how can I iterate over a map using forEach in angular?

Just to give more clarity my requirement is something like that: I need values to be passed to the server as key, value pair, only if I'm not wrong, suppose if I use object properties the key of the object will be fixed something like

```
       {"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","$$hashKey":"003"}]
```

but my server is expecting something like

```
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Created an plunkr edit  http://plnkr.co/edit/t2g6Dl831HGyjD6uSdf3?p=preview

Comment: Just a side note: You are aware that `Map` is an ES6 feature only present on cutting-edge browsers...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes i am aware ,i am using it in Chrome 39 which supports ECMA6 features

Comment: I would assume, that you would iterate like over object properties?

Comment: Which supports ***some*** ES6 features. :-)

Comment: @Eugene Correct me if i am wrong,if i iterate like over object properties  my output is like this {"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","$$hashKey":"003"}] but my server is expecting like this "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  is there any other go to solve this.

Comment: Should be as far as I know.

Comment: really not clear what your issue is regarding server

Comment: @charlietfl i have a Map object i want to iterate over it using ng-repeat since the key,value are of the map object are from the user we are not aware of key of a map i have created a plunkr u can have a look http://plnkr.co/edit/t2g6Dl831HGyjD6uSdf3?p=preview

Comment: why make it so complicated and not just use `{key: 'user key',value:'user value'}` ?

Comment: @charlietfl as i explained above my server side code is expecting it to be {'userkey':uservalue}

Comment: you can remap to send to server or adjust server code, or remap for view or store 2 versions locally, one for server one for view. `ng-repeat` isn't ideally suited for dynamic key names without you parsing the data structure again

Comment: @charlietfl thankyou but can u suggest me which angular directive is suited for dynamic key names?

Comment: no as usually just do own mapping when needed

Comment: is this you are trying to do: http://plnkr.co/edit/yH0ar7gug9T7uymv

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS 1.x does not know how to use Javascript iterators, so you'll have to convert the Map object to an Array first using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Controller:

```
$scope.inputHeadersArray = Array.from($scope.inputHeaders);
```

View:

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="header in inputHeadersArray">
  {{header[0]}} : {{header[1]}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

`[...headerObj]` or `[...headerObj.entries()]` to got two dimensions array. and iterate them.

or `[...headerObj.keys()]` and `[...headerObj.values()]` for regular array.

Answer (score -2):

here are few changes in your code. http://plnkr.co/edit/gpc1mPsZrl2QVXbnWZKA?p=preview

```
app = angular.module('testDemo', []);

app.controller('submitCtrl',function($scope) {
 $scope.header={};
 $scope.inputHeaders=[];

 $scope.addHeader = function() {

 $scope.inputHeaders.push($scope.header);
 $scope.header = {};
 $scope.header.key='';
 $scope.header.value='';

}

$scope.log=function(){
 //alert('in log');
 $scope.inputHeaders.forEach(function (key, value) {
 console.log(key, value);
});
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller='submitCtrl'>
<div >

<input type="text"  class="=form-control" ng-model="header.key" placeholder="Key">
<input type="text" class="=form-control" ng-model="header.value" placeholder="value">
<button class="btn btn-sucess" ng-click="addHeader()">Add</button>
<button class="btn btn-sucess" ng-click="log()">Log</button>
<div>
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="header in inputHeaders">


 <!-- need to to work on this logic -->
 <div ng-show="inputHeaders.length>=1">
 <input type="text"   ng-model="header.value" />
 <input type="text"   ng-model="header.key" />
 </div>

</li>
</ul>            
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: just saying `here are some changes` and not identifying what thos changes are or why they help is not a reasonable way to answer a question. People shouldn't have be human diff tools  to  see your solutions

Comment: -1. The question is specifically about a javascript Map object, not on how to bind to objects. More on maps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.